# CSS repeating-linear-gradient broken at Safari 11?

Tags: css, safari, repeating-linear-gradient

I just upgraded OSX to High Sierra, and Safari to 11.01, and my repeating linear gradient is all out of whack. Is this a known issue with the latest version of Safari?

```
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-64deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 5px,
    rgba(191, 159, 209, 0.8) 1px,
    rgba(191, 159, 209, 0.8) 6px
  );
```

Image shows comparison to Chrome which still behaves as expected ([codepen here](https://codepen.io/awestmoreland/pen/paRwJG?editors=0100)).

[image: Visual comparison]